# Why does tilde ('~') go before numeric digits in NTFS file names?

Tags: windows, ntfs, unicode, filenames

I have a folder structure in which the folder names start with numbers. After a while, some folders (or, rather, the info they contain) become "archived", and I don't want them to visually clutter the space of the parent folder.

My solution so far is to rename the folders (as non-intrusively as possible) so that the "archived" folders go to the end of the list. I decided to go with adding a tilde character (`~`) to the beginning of the folder names, expecting to see `~`-prefixed folders below the number-prefixed ones when sorting by name in ascending order.

But, instead of something like

```
parent folder:
  123
  456
  789
  ~012
```

I see this:

```
parent folder:
  ~012
  123
  456
  789
```

That's surprising, considering that NTFS [uses Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/character-sets-used-in-file-names) for its file name characters, and tilde's Unicode value is higher than of the `[0-9]` characters, which should put it after in the lexicographic order.

What's the reason of the behavior I'm observing and how to I make `~`-prefixed folders be sorted after the number-prefixed ones?

**Edit:** To display the folder contents, I mostly use FAR Manager. But so far its sorting by name looks the same as in Windows Explorer. So a solution that works for Windows Explorer would also work for FAR Manager.

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the filenames? Please [edit] the question and be specific.

Comment: Sorting in Windows isn't always by numeric value of characters. In Windows explorer normal punctuation characters precede alphabetic. This includes the tilde.

Comment: @LMiller7 is there any formal description of the character ordering in Windows file names? So that I could possibly pick up a symbol that would actually precede the numeric digits.

Comment: Newer Windows also uses some sort of "smart" numbering detection. This is mostly so you don't get a sequence like 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 but also seems to detect slight character misalignments and adjusts the sequence to match the numbers despite any character table ordering.

Comment: @Semisonic MSDN states only that punctuation characters precede alphabetic. Which ones they are I don't know. There are only a few ASCII characters above 'z' and I suspect they behave the same way. There are many characters in the extended ASCII range above 160 that would work. I am sure you can find one that is suitable and not too difficult to enter.